# grep from output and do something on first occurence

Tags: linux, bash, process

I have a stream of logs from a specific tool on my server with persistent output. 
I've say it's like

```
task 3 done
all is ok
added another task
something made
```

I cannot grep from output file by a reason, but I have an opportunity of make something through pipes or output streams:

```
./myexecutablefile | grep something
```

In this case I receive highlighted "something" if it appeared in output.

I want to make something if first occurrence is met, but i don't know how, because of continuous stream. For example my goal is to kill process if I will see some error.

Surely this doesn't work, && kill will begin after executable ends

```
./myexecutable | grep 'Error occured' && kill -9 myexecutable
```

Comment: And you want this proccess to continue? Or just monitor a stream, and when you grep what you want, do something and that's it?

Comment: Don't use `kill -9` unless you **know** that the program is buggy and will not respond to regular signals (in which case maybe don't trust it enough to run it in the first place).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `-q` option in `grep`:

```
./myexecutable | grep -q 'Error occured' && kill -9 myexecutable
```

Comment: What does `--line-buffered` do and why is it useful here?

Comment: It forces output to be line buffered.

Comment: I am not 100% sure if that is required here. Will test it once I get back to my computer.

Comment: I thought that with `-q`, there is no output to buffer?

Comment: Hmm I believe you're right and `--line-buffered` may not be needed here (editing now)

Comment: is kill -9 needed here, -q will also kill a task?

Comment: Yes `-q` will only cause termination of `myexecutable | grep` but here `kill` will also allow you to kill any arbitrary process.

Answer (score 2):

If you are interested in the first occurrence only, you can use the `-m` switch of grep:

```
./myexecutablefile | grep -m1 something && do_something
```

This will still output the matching line. To suppress that, you can turn on `-q`, but then, you don't need `-m1` anymore:

```
./myexecutablefile | grep -q something && do_something
```

Comment: thanks! Don't you also know, is there a way to show full output in terminal, but still waiting by grep the first occurrence?

Comment: @StasErem: You can try something like `| tee >(grep -q something && do-something)`